# Generate Complete DFS Paths using networkx

Tags: python, networkx, depth-first-search

I am trying to generate complete path list instead of the optimized one. Better explained using the below example.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 5), (5, 6)])
```

The above code create a Graph with edges `0=>1=>2=>3` and `0=>1=>2=>4` and `0=>5=>6`

All I want is to extract all paths from `0`.

I tried:

```
>> list(nx.dfs_edges(G, 0))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5), (5, 6)]
```

All I want is:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 4), (0, 5, 6)]
```

Is there any pre-existing method from `networkx` which can be used? If not, any way to write an optimal method that can do the job?

**Note**: My problem is limited to the given example. No more corner cases possible.

**Note2**: For simplification the data is generated. In my case, the edges list is coming from data set. Assumption is given a graph and a node (Say `0`), Can we generate all paths?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)])
G.add_edges_from([(0, 5), (5, 6)])

pathes = []

path = [0]
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(G, 0):
    if edge[0] == path[-1]:
        # node of path
        path.append(edge[1])
    else:
        # new path
        pathes.append(path)
        search_index = 2
        while search_index <= len(path):
            if edge[0] == path[-search_index]:
                path = path[:-search_index + 1] + [edge[1]]
                break
            search_index += 1
        else:
            raise Exception("Wrong path structure?", path, edge)
# append last path
pathes.append(path)
print(pathes)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 5, 6]]
```